# Future forms; "will" or "going to"

Tags: grammar

Would you please tell me the right choice to this question:

Liverpool's players are known to be skilled. They (are going to win / will win) the match easily.

Comment: Dear tchrist, thanks for your reply, but The question I asked was included in the GSSC final exam in Egypt. Students had to choose ONLY one choice. I'll type the MCQ again with its all options: Liverpool's players are known to be skilled. They (are going to win / will win / win / are winning) the match easily.

Comment: This is something like the fifth time I've seen this exact question posted in the past 24 hours. I find it unusual that such a relatively large number of people would get this exam and then ask about it here.